# Springframework UserDetailsService error

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to create my own UserDetailsService with the spring framework.

I've made the following simple class, but I'm getting an error: `Cannot convert value of type [com.mycompany.project.MyDetailsService] to required type org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService]`

Full Class:

```
package com.mycompany.myproject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;


public class MyDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyDetailsService.class);

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {        
        return null; //It'll do something here later
    }
}
```

I can include the fill stack trace if that's helpful.  It's just long and doesn't fit in the box easily, so here the full text of the error message before the stack trace.

> 28542 [main] ERROR StackTrace - Sanitizing stacktrace: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'parent'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#15': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'casAuthenticationProvider' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'casAuthenticationProvider' defined in file [/usr/share/jetty/resources/OWFsecurityContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.mycompany.myproject.MyDetailsService' to required type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' for property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.mycompany.project.MyDetailsService] to reuired type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Security Context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">
    <sec:http entry-point-ref="casProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
        ...
    </sec:http>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="casAuthenticationProvider" />
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="casProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
                <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/cas_failed.jsp" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="proxyGrantingTicketStorage" ref="proxyGrantingTicketStorage" />
        <property name="proxyReceptorUrl" value="/secure/receptor" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="casProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginUrl" value="..." />
        <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="casAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
        <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
        <property name="ticketValidator" ref="ticketValidator" />
        <property name="key" value="an_id_for_this_auth_provider_only" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="ticketValidator"
        class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="..." />
        <property name="proxyGrantingTicketStorage" ref="proxyGrantingTicketStorage" />
        <property name="proxyCallbackUrl"
            value="..." />
    </bean>

    <bean id="proxyGrantingTicketStorage"
        class="org.jasig.cas.client.proxy.ProxyGrantingTicketStorageImpl" />

    <bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
        <property name="service"
            value="..." />
        <property name="sendRenew" value="false" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="userService" class="com.mycompany.myproject.MyDetailsService" >
    </bean>

    ...
</beans>
```

Comment: Can we please see a snippet of your OWFsecurityContext.xml file?

Comment: Sure.  I'm not sure how much you need but I posted most of it above.  Let me know if filling in any of the ellipses would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: I can't see what's wrong. For what it's worth, the CasAuthenticationProvider (which is what is spitting the dummy) does say that the setUserDetailsService is deprecated and you should use setAuthenticationUserDetailsService, which takes in a different user details service. See http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/cas/authentication/CasAuthenticationProvider.html#setUserDetailsService%28org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService%29 Whether that's the issue or not - I can't say.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I tried changing the class to implement AuthenticationUserDetailsService and the security context to use authenticationUserDetailsService, but I still get a similar error except this time it can't convert to AuthenticationUserDetailsService.